# Yii2. Bootstrap3. Navbar collapse перестал работать

Tags: yii2, bootstrap

Имеется проект на Yii2 framework, пытаюсь сделать адаптивную навигацию через bootstrap3, но при узкой ширине браузера, при нажатии на кнопку, которая должна развернуть элементы навигации, то ничего не происходит. Если этот же код вставить в codepen.io, то он работает как нужно. В чем может быть проблема?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">  
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>      
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown"></li>
        <li class="dropdown"></li>
        <li class="dropdown"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

В $depends была добавлена строка 'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'

Answer (score 1):

Более чем уверен, что не подключен bootstrap.js